# How do you use a Json body with multipart in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have an API method that accepts any number of images along with a Json body. The only way I've found to do this so far is to declare every individual Json element as a Part, along with the images. My problem is that this API method can have a dynamic amount of Json elements, so I can't declare the method call in the rest adapter. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
@Multipart
@Post("/myapi")
Response doTheApi(@Part("json") Request request, @Part("json[image]") TypedFile image)
```

Where `Request` is a model object that I want to be serialized into json. It has Lists, Maps, and custom serialization code for inner models. This, however, does not work. Is there a way to still use Gson's serialization with Retrofit when using multipart?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Tukajo: Sorta. I ended up passing in a TypedString which was the JSON body, and wrote a util method to convert JSON to a TypedString, and that worked.